# Access First Graph

Tags: r, text, graph, plot, performanceanalytics

So I am using the PerformanceAnalytics package to plot performance summary of a simple PnL series so

```
library(xts)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

dates <- structure(c(14008, 14011, 14012, 14013, 14014, 14015, 14018, 14019, 14020, 14021),
                   class = "Date")

PnL.xts = structure(c(0, -0.00510803851321091, -0.0102109843849305, -0.00138369232677364, 
                      -0.00255257489213331, -0.00200279255353461, 0.0104232666033935, 
                      0.00181846800788812, 4.72633257030091e-05, 0.0138334493571853),
                    .Dim = c(10L, 1L),
                    index = structure(c(1210291200, 1210550400, 1210636800, 1210723200,
                                        1210809600, 1210896000, 1211155200, 1211241600,
                                        1211328000, 1211414400),
                                      tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"),
                   .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date",
                   .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", .Dimnames = list(NULL, "PnL"),
                   class = c("xts", "zoo"))

PnL.cum = cumsum(PnL.xts)
ret.ann = Return.annualized(PnL.xts, geometric = FALSE)
ret.cum = Return.cumulative(PnL.xts, geometric = FALSE)
ret.min = min(PnL.cum)
stdev = StdDev.annualized(PnL.xts)
sharpe = SharpeRatio.annualized(PnL.xts, geometric = FALSE)

stats = paste(paste("Annualized Return:", percent(round(ret.ann, 5))),
              paste("Cumulative Return:", percent(round(ret.cum, 5))),
              paste("Standard Deviation:", round(stdev, 5)),
              paste("Sharpe Ratio:", round(sharpe, 5)), sep = '\n' )
lag = 1
descr = paste("Following fitted Granger model - ", lag, " day lag", sep = "")

charts.PerformanceSummary(R = PnL.xts, geometric = FALSE)
text(midrange(dates),ret.min, labels = stats, cex = 1)
mtext(descr, side = 3, line = 31)
```

However, I want to add some descriptive text into the cumulative PnL chart such as annualized return, cumulative return, standard deviation, and sharpe. How can I paste this into the whitespace in the first  graph?

If I plotted the graph by itself, I could just do it with the above code. However, since the charts.PerformanceSummary function automatically plots 3 graphs, I can only access the 3rd graph it seems. Is there any way to access the first of 3 graphs printed by a function, so that I can write text on it relative to its own coordinates?

Here is an example of what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nehMc.png. But in this case, I had to manually, test values of the y coordinate until I found somthing that worked. Thanks!

Comment: You may wanna add the required packages so your example's fully reproducible.

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead and looked into the charts.PerformanceSummary function itself and found that it was just plotting 3 graphs, so I should be able to add text to the first plot if I copy the function with additional parameters.